# Runnable war with maven, jetty9, spring4 and no web.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, embedded-jetty

I want to create a runnable war with Jetty9 and Spring4 and still keep it as deployable war (sort of like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/))

The war file is built with Maven so that maven-war-plugin moves main class(WebAppRunner)  to the top of file tree, overlays all the jetty-* jars, javax*  jars and spring-web.jar inside war (to be accessible to main class) and sets main class in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.

The main class starts Jetty like this:

```
ProtectionDomain domain = WebAppRunner.class.getProtectionDomain();
URL location = domain.getCodeSource().getLocation();

WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setContextPath( "/" );
context.setWar( location.toExternalForm() );
context.setParentLoaderPriority( true );
context.setConfigurations( new Configuration[] { 
  new AnnotationConfiguration(),
  new WebInfConfiguration(), 
  new WebXmlConfiguration(),
  new MetaInfConfiguration(),
  new PlusConfiguration(), 
  new JettyWebXmlConfiguration() 
} );

Server server = new Server( 8080 );
server.dumpStdErr();
server.setHandler( context );
try {
  server.start();
  server.join();
} catch ( Exception e ) {
  LOG.warn( e );
}
```

Jetty itself starts without problems and during startup WebAppContext [scans through WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes folders inside the war file](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/Jetty_Classloading#Introduction) to pickup [SpringServletContainerInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html) as implementation of [ServletContainerInitializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) which in turn should start the web application.

However [AnnotationConfiguration.getNonExcludedInitializers](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-annotations/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/annotations/AnnotationConfiguration.java#L852) method doesn't find any initializers (ServiceLoader returns empty iterable).

I created a small demo project on [github](https://github.com/ragnarruutel/java8-jetty9-spring4-noxml) to demonstrate this (it overrides AnnotationConfiguration with MyAnnotationConfiguration only to add log entries). You can build with:

```
mvn clean compile war:exploded antrun:run war:war
```

and run with:

```
java -jar target/myapp.war
```

or to get more logging:

```
java -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG -jar target/myapp.war
```

Here are few of articles/issues/sources that I've already looked through: [1](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2013/05/embedding-jetty9-spring-mvc.html), [2](http://kielczewski.eu/2013/11/using-embedded-jetty-spring-mvc/), [3](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Setting_a_Web_Application_Context), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458440/executable-war-file-that-starts-jetty-without-maven), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491407/create-a-executable-jar-using-maven-and-jetty), [6](http://blog.anvard.org/articles/2013/10/09/embedded-jetty-executable-maven.html), [7](https://github.com/viesis/spring-jetty9-no-webxml/blob/master/src/main/java/demo/app/run/AppJettyRunner.java), [8](http://jetty.4.x6.nabble.com/Having-trouble-using-Embedded-Jetty-and-WebApplicationInitializer-with-a-WarFile-deployment-td4963118.html), [9](http://steveliles.github.io/setting_up_embedded_jetty_8_and_spring_mvc_with_maven_and_no_xml.html)

Comment: Did you have a look at [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)? It makes it easy to create a stand-alone runnable application that has an embedded Jetty or Tomcat, and you can also package your app as a WAR that can be deployed the traditional way.

Comment: I did and I'm considering it as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration should be added as last configuration, otherwise jar's in the WEB-INF/lib dir are not added to the classpath
2. in pom.xml plugins should not be in pluginManagement block
3. remove overlay spring-web

Comment: Sweet :) Its working! I updated the project on [github](https://github.com/ragnarruutel/java8-jetty9-spring4-noxml) for anyone looking for reference.